# After adding elements to a div with javascript, an untouched existing link stops working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html like this

```
<div id='myArea'></div>
<div id='aDifferentUnrelatedArea'></div>
<a href='#' id='closeButton' class='myButton'>Close</a>
```

the button has a listener like this

```
$('#closeButton').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var myNode = document.getElementById("myArea");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
    }
});
```

and I add elements to `myArea` like this

```
document.getElementById('myArea').innerHTML = 'a title';
var newElement = document.createElement('a');
newElement.setAttribute('href', "#");
newElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('a string'));
document.getElementById('myArea').appendChild(newElement);
```

Before I add elements, the `Close` button looks fine. There's nothing to close, but my hover css is applied to it and my cursor becomes the clickable one. After I add elements to `myArea` like this, the button acts more like a picture and there is no click related to it (it doesn't act like an `<a>` tag anymore nor does it do the click event).

Comment: Besides that your `click`-handler is not closed properly it seems to work: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3m0qgvLh/)

Comment: not seeing an issue besides the syntax error. Post relevant CSS?

Comment: I added the css, but it also doesn't clear the area so I think there's some issue causing both problems. Also, your example does work and that's strange that mine isn't. The only extra details I can think of is that I add a lot of `<a>` and `<small>` elements, and the button works if I comment everything except the `innerHTML` part (ie it breaks when I try to append any child node).

Comment: You mention you are adding elements dynamically after page load, how are you accomplishing this?

Comment: I have a form with a text input and a submit. On submit, it searches the google books api with the input. Then I loop the response and add each title as an `<a>` or `<div>` and its description as `<small>`.

Comment: like @empiric I can drop in your code into a jsfiddle and it will work properly. It must be something else in your code. I would suggest inspecting the code in your browser and checking if the click event is still associated with the close button.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion but thanks for helping me find the problem. The actual problem was I had this floating footer button at the bottom of the page. It seemed to take up the whole line's functionalities (I mean anything on the same line as the button would behave like a picture). I just added extra space at the bottom of the body so nothing would be on the same line as the footer.